# How to hittest for all instances of a movieclip - ACTIONSCRIPT 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, hittest

I am making a tower defense game, and have gotten it to the point that my towers shoot bullets at appropriate intervals.  But I need to be able to remove the movieclips.  For example, if a tower shoots a bullet, it makes a copy of the bullet movieclip, which is aimed at a duplicate of the specific enemy.  However, I cannot figure out how to configure the hitTest.  Is there any way to gt the hittest to check for all child movieclips duplicated from a specific object?

EDIT:  I added this function, which is to execute every second.  But for some reason, it does not confirm the hits.

```
function checkHits(){//checks for hits between enemies and bullets
for (var zz = 0; zz < bulletArray.length; zz += 1)//checks for each bullet
{
    for(var yy=0;yy<enemiesArray.length;yy+=1){//checks for each enemy
        trace("enemies loc"+yy+":"+enemiesArray[yy]);
        trace("bullet loc"+zz+":"+bulletArray[zz]);
        if(bulletArray[zz].hitTest(enemiesArray[yy])){
            trace("HIT!");
           removeMovieClip(bulletArray[zz]);
           removeMovieClip(enemiesArray[yy]);
           bulletArray.splice(zz,1);
           bulletArray.splice(yy,1);
           }//end if
    }//end for
}//end for
```

}

```
function dupeCircle()
{
//trace("Dupe circle initiated");
duplicateMovieClip(circlebase, "_root.circle" + circleCount, circleCount);
bulletArray.push("circle" + circleCount);
trace(bulletArray[0]._width);
circleCount += 1;
}
```

This is the code for the object which adds the circles.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep an array with all of the movieclips you want to test in it and then loop through that array and check each one.  So whenever you add one to the screen, add it to that array.  Then when you want to test, test everyone in that array.  If you want to remove it, remove it from the array and the screen.

***EDIT***

Here is what I would think to do in this case...

```
function dupeCircle() 
{    
    //trace("Dupe circle initiated"); 
    bulletArray.push(duplicateMovieClip(circlebase, "_root.circle" + circleCount, circleCount));
    circleCount += 1; 
 }
```

Basically just store the actual movieclip in the array and then you can do what you were trying to do with the `bulletArray[index].hitTest` and it should hopefully work. (Do the same thing where you store the actual movieclip for the other array also)

Comment: I thought of that, but how do I manage when to check it?  If I have 30 enemies on the screen and 30 bullets, should each instance check constantly?  Or is the better way to have a stacked "for each" array for each bullet and each enemy, which runs through all of them; and have that one check every second?

Comment: Well there are many different methods you could use for when to check.  One thing I like to do when making a game is create a "main loop" because I am used to c++ and there is always a main loop.  I do not know if this is the best way to do it in flash but I do it like that and have not had any problems.  I think that a timer is a good way to implement this loop.  Your code you added looks like the right idea.  Not sure why it isn't hitting.  Try posting the code where you call that function (the event listener part) and where you add enemies and bullets to the array.

Comment: I have checked and through troubleshooting have found that it recognizes the objects in the array.  For example, I can use removeMovieClip(enemiesArray[yy]) to get the enemy off of the stage, but I cannot access any methods or properties ON the movieclip.  I think that is my problem, since I am using the hitTest function on the movieclip.  Is there some reason I wouldn't be able to access the properties?

EDIT:  They all come up undefined

Comment: And for what it's worth, the checkHits function is set to go off every frame

Comment: Well if all of the properties are NULL something must not be right... Post the code where you add it to the array

Comment: Hmm I'll edit my post to what I think you should try (to what I would normally do).. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do by storing just "circle#" in the array.  I usually store the actual object... See my edited post above...

Comment: I put in this code.

duplicateMovieClip(circlebase, "_root.circle" + circleCount, circleCount);

I was not using root because it is a root-level function.  Even with your line, it still comes up undefined when I try to check the width of the object.

Comment: function dupeCircle()
{
 //trace("Dupe circle initiated");
 duplicateMovieClip(circlebase, "_root.circle" + circleCount, circleCount);
 bulletArray.push("circle" + circleCount);
 
 circleCount += 1;
}


This is the code.  It is an identical method except for the change to the duplicate method

Comment: That code is the same as your original post... but you are saying you tried directly pushing the movieclip into the array and that is not working?  Edit your original post to have exactly what the most recent code you are trying is and where you are trying to access the width property so we can see exactly what is going on.

Comment: I edited it.  I just had it check after the initial push because I know it will be there and I only needed one check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7894/discussion-between-nick-and-m-laing)

Answer (score 0):

You are removing 2 times from bulletArray:

```
       bulletArray.splice(zz,1);
       bulletArray.splice(yy,1);
```

Last one should be enemy removal I guess. maybe this throws error when you later try to remove an enemy you already removed from the stage?

Comment: If I splice first, then when I try to remove, it will remove the wrong object, I believe

Comment: I mean you are removing bullet 2 times and you are not removing the enemy from the enemy array. Should the last line not be enemiesArray.splice(yy,1) instead of bulletArray.splice(yy,1);?

Comment: Thanks.  I had missed that, but I don't think it was what was causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, the case it's actually not possible, since if it's removed from the stage it will not hittest anything. Don't know then :/